# lower_bound() return the last element

Tags: c++, algorithm

When I solve the problem of [392.Is Subsequence](https://leetcode.com/problems/is-subsequence/). on Leetcode.

When I using the function of `lower_bound()`, I can't understand the difference between I want to find the last element and it doesn't found then return the last element.

This is my code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool isSubsequence(string s, string t) {
        vector<vector<int>> temp(26);
        for (int i = 0; i < t.length(); ++i)
            temp[t[i]-'a'].push_back(i);
        int index = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
            auto it = upper_bound(temp[s[i]-'a'].begin(), temp[s[i]-'a'].end(), index);

            //if the last element is we want to find what will happen?
            if (it == temp[s[i]-'a'].end()) return false;
            index = *it;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

If the last element is we want to find what will happen?

Answer (score 2):

[`end()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) does not point to the last element, it points *beyond* the last element. Emphasis mine:

> Returns an iterator to the end (i.e. the element **after the** last element) of the given container c or array array.

If the last element is what you want to find, `lower_bound` will return `end() - 1`